# Multiple Linked List in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a problem about Linked Lists. I already know how to create structures and linked list. But now I have to create arbitrary number of linked list which are also be kept in another structure. Which means :

```
struct list{int x, struct list *next; };
struct parent{int x, struct list  *head, struct parent *next;}
```

And after lists are created when i enter this input for example "123134" linked list should look like :

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

And for example 1 will contain 2->3 list inside of it, 3 will contain 1->4 list inside of it.

I need a starting point and a spark from you. So how can i do this?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a tree?

Comment: You want to create a list of lists? Ok... What is stopping you? You already have the structs defined.

Comment: the problem is i can't figure out how to create a lot of linked lists. You know, i before simply create only one list and do the work on it. Will i need a lot of head pointers or etc. now. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Draw your list diagram, which often helps.

```
Start
 |
list1 -> node1 -> node2
 |
list2 -> node_a -> node_b -> node_c
 |
list3 {empty}
 |
list4 -> node_1A
```

Given a diagram like the above, the `lists` have two links, one to their own nodes, another to another list.  Some objects may need more than one link field.

In your case, draw a diagram.  Try inserting a new item.  Write down the steps you take (and draw).

If you supply more details in your question, more people will assist.

For an example of a list with nodes containing many lists, see a **BTree** data structure.  Each node contains an array of links to other "subtrees".

Comment: thanks for the comment. Actually i want to put some code to get people's ideas about this issue. This is why i'm waiting :)

Comment: Did you make some progress with that?